# Border is overlapping the child and sub-child of li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to develop a bordered box using ul li,

I have applied borders but the problem is when I applied border bottom and border top for li, the first 1px border-bottom is overlapping with second li border-top and it is appearing like 2px border.

My code is below,

```css
.main-permissions-box{
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-permissions-box li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:8px;
  border-top:1px solid #555;
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box > ul> li{
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box > li:first-child{
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box ul ul li{
  border-left:1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box > ul{
  padding: 0;margin: 0;
}
.permission-text{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade assign-menu-popup" role="dialog" id="assign_menu_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content clearfix">
   <div class="main-permissions-box">
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Pre Sales</span>
   </li>
   <ul>
    <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClas">
    <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
    </li>
    <ul>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option One</span>
     </li>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option Two</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
         <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
          <span class="permission-text">Customer</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to apply border so that it wont appear like it is overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you want, I'd be inclined to use a table instead of an unordered list. However, you can get the effect you want by using `outline` styles instead of borders. You'll need to add an extra 1px margin to the boxes in order to get these outlines to overlap, and you need a bit more adjustment to get things lined up down the left side, but it should work:

```css
.main-permissions-box{
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-permissions-box li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:8px;
  margin: 1px;
  outline: 1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box > ul> li{
  margin-left: 0;
}
.main-permissions-box > li:first-child{
}
.main-permissions-box ul ul li{
}
.main-permissions-box > ul{
  padding: 0;margin: 0;
}
.permission-text{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade assign-menu-popup" role="dialog" id="assign_menu_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content clearfix">
   <div class="main-permissions-box">
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Pre Sales</span>
   </li>
   <ul>
    <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClas">
    <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
    </li>
    <ul>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option One</span>
     </li>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option Two</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
         <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
          <span class="permission-text">Customer</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On second thoughts, adding `margin: -1px;` to the `.main-permissions-box li` rules as suggested by @MrLister would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `margin-bottom` to the list elements. Here is the code:

```css
    .main-permissions-box{
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-permissions-box li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:8px;
  border-top:1px solid #555;
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box > ul> li{
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.main-permissions-box > li:first-child{
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
}
.main-permissions-box ul ul li{
  border-left:1px solid #555;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.main-permissions-box > ul{
  padding: 0;margin: 0;
}
.permission-text{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade assign-menu-popup" role="dialog" id="assign_menu_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content clearfix">
   <div class="main-permissions-box">
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Pre Sales</span>
   </li>
   <ul>
    <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClas">
    <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
    </li>
    <ul>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option One</span>
     </li>
     <li class="label-check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
    <span class="permission-text">Option Two</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
         <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li class="label-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
          <span class="permission-text">Customer</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Increase the margin by the amount you wish. Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: it is giving spaces between li, and i don't want that spaces

Comment: @charankumar This answer is very close, and you did not state your problem very well. Try margins of `-1px` instead.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the suggestion. True, the question was unclear of what was required.

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered but answering if someone wants to solve it by `border` and not with `outline` or `negative margins`

This excerpt from below code helps with **any** kind of nesting and not only the nesting in this question

```
ul > li{ border-bottom: 1px solid #555; }
ul > li:last-child{ border-bottom: none; }
ul > li:first-child{ border-top: 1px solid #555; }
ul ul > li:first-child{ border-top: none; }
```

First three rules make sure an individual ul is bordered correctly and the last rules takes care of the nesting

```css
.main-permissions-box {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-permissions-box li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.main-permissions-box ul ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
}

.main-permissions-box>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.permission-text {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.main-permissions-box ul>li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.main-permissions-box ul>li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.main-permissions-box ul>li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
}

.main-permissions-box ul ul>li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade assign-menu-popup" role="dialog" id="assign_menu_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content clearfix">
      <div class="main-permissions-box">
        <ul>
          <li class="label-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
            <span class="permission-text">Pre Sales</span>
          </li>
          <ul>
            <li class="label-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClas">
              <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li class="label-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
                <span class="permission-text">Option One</span>
              </li>
              <li class="label-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
                <span class="permission-text">Option Two</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li class="label-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
            <span class="permission-text">Schedule Consultation</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li class="label-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass">
            <span class="permission-text">Customer</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```